# Получить в атрибутах класса HttpContext.Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть в модели атрибут к свойству для проверки капчи. Текст капчи хранится в сессии `context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");`
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    RegisterFizikModel.InputModel inputModel = (RegisterFizikModel.InputModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
    _captcha = validationContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");

    if (inputModel.Captcha != _captcha)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Получается ошибка:

> `ValidationContext` не содержит `HttpContext`

Как можно получить из сессии в атрибуте свойства значение `HttpContext.Session.GetString`?

Comment: Вы пишете атрибут для валидации или что? Не совсем понятно

Comment: Да атрибут валидации

Comment: Т.е. вы его к свойству класса модели применяете?

Comment: Да к свойству модели. ` [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Введите число с картинки")]
            [ValidCaptcha]
            [StringLength(4)]
            public string Captcha { get; set; }`

Comment: Нет к свойству класса модели

Comment: Ваш класс атрибута реализует [`IModelValidator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.imodelvalidator?view=aspnetcore-2.1)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86272/discussion-between---and--nop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш класс реализует интерфейс `IModelValidator`, то вы должны реализовать код для валидации в методе `Validate`. Этот метод получает параметр `ModelValidationContext context` и из него вы можете добраться до данных сессии:

```
context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Session...
```